# Change base URL in my App if server changes

Tags: android, server

I  have an Android App on google play store, I want to change my server for this android app, Without change any code or any update on google play store.

Comment: not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to change server api link from android application itself with out play store update.

First you must create a screen for server api change and give login credential to admin users to access the page.

In the server api change page must contain a edit text to input url and a save button. While press save button check the entered uri is valid or not. If the uri is valid then save it to shared preference. And use the shared preference uri to access your api calls.

Hope this will help to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Firebase Remote Config as a solution in your app to provide base url for your server.